# Apache POI - Reading .xlsx and .xls files using usermodel

Tags: exception, apache-poi

I have code using Apache POI written to read data from .xls worksheets using hssf. I'd like for the program to read .xlsx worksheets as well using org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel. Here is the code:
(_fileName is passed into the function)

java.io.FileInputStream fs = new java.io.FileInputStream(_fileName)
Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);

It throws the following exception for a .xlsx file: InavlidFormatException - Can't read the content types part !
I'm doing this in Visual Studio, so the output window says "A first chance exception of type 'org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException' occurred in poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.dll'.

And for a .xls file, the output window says "A first chance exception of type 'java.io.IOException' occurred in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll"

It would be great if someone could help me solve this issue. Been working on this since yesterday.

Thank you so much!!!
Soundarya

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your .xlsx file isn't a valid one. I'd double check you're passing in the correct file, and that it's really an Excel one (and not something else - in your .xlsx case I suspect you just have a normal zip file)

Comment: i checked the file and it was correct..its weird though because when i wrote another program that took a .xls file and reproduced it in .xlsx format, excel complained that it was invalid and wouldn't open it, so i had to "repair" it and then the original program i had accepted this file. the issue was with the dll's i used because copies of those files were in multiple locations the program could access. i just had to delete the duplicate copies. thanks a bunch anyway!